# Returning list of list from an UDF: expected zero arguments for construction of ClassDict (for numpy.core.multiarray._reconstruct)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions, sqldatatypes

I would like to output two columns that I return as map, one of which is a `nd.array` of floating point numbers. I am having trouble converting it to the correct return type in PySpark.

```
def get_vectors(feature_map):
    ids, inputs = zip(*[
        (k,  v) for d in feature_map for k, v in d.items()
    ])

   #vectors object will be returned by another method, this is just dummy code to simulate the data. It is an nd.array of floating point numbers
    vectors = []
    for item in inputs :
      vectors.append([1.0,2.0,3.0])
    vectors = np.array(vectors,float)
    return dict(zip(ids, list(vectors)))

gen_vectors_udf  = f.udf(get_vectors,t.MapType(t.StringType(),t.ArrayType(t.ArrayType(t.FloatType()))))
```

I get the following error when I call this udf.

> expected zero arguments for construction of ClassDict (for numpy.core.multiarray._reconstruct).

Can some help me understand how to convert the `nd.array` to PySpark type?

On the other hand, if I convert the `nd.array` to list of strings, it seems to work perfectly fine:

```
def get_vectors(feature_map):
    ids, inputs = zip(*[
        (k,  v) for d in feature_map for k, v in d.items()
    ])

    #vectors object will be returned by another method, this is just dummy code to simulate the data. It is an nd.array of floating point numbers
    vectors = []

    for item in inputs:
      vectors.append([1.0,2.0,3.0])
    vectors = np.array(vectors,float)
    output = [str(k) for k in vectors]
    return dict(zip(ids, output ))

gen_vectors_udf = f.udf(get_vectors,t.MapType(t.StringType(),t.StringType()))
```